# How to use SearchView.SetOnCloseListener in xamarin android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

For now when i click button "x" it crash so i tried to add SetOnCloseListener and it looks like that
 `src.SetOnCloseListener(new SearchView.IOnCloseListener() { } );`
 with error "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'SearchView.IOnCloseListener" i cant find any example of how to use it.

Comment: Are you sure that shouldn't be new SearchView.OnCloseListener()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SearchView has an event named 'Close', which you would use like so:

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView();
searchView.Close += (sender, e) =>
{
    // Do stuff here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give up "oncloselistener". Instead,  you can get your menuItem, then `setOnActionExpandListener`. Then override unimplents methods.

Here's an example of it:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("*******","onMenuItemActionExpand");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
    //do what you want to when close the sesarchview
    //remember to return true;
    Log.d("*******","onMenuItemActionCollapse");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well I've done it in Android studio so I'd say more like Java